# Why won't my Regex work? (Very simple)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use the regex:

```
<td>(.*)<\/td><td>(.*)<\/td>
```

To match the data from this:

```
<td>over079</td><td>37.123.86.116</td></tr><tr><td>1346968</td><td>rektheace</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>1346967</td><td>rektheace</td><td>173.245.67.214</td>
```

So I can extract each one, but it seems to be just returning:

```
<td>over079</td><td>37.123.86.116</td></tr><tr><td>1346968</td><td>rektheace</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>1346967</td><td>rektheace</td><td>173.245.67.214</td>
```

Any reason why?

Comment: Obligatory http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1316346

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<td>(.*?)<\/td><td>(.*?)<\/td>
```

Make `*` `non greedy`

or

Use

```
<td>((?:(?!<\/td>).)*)<\/td><td>(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)<\/td>
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/aD7aH2/3

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to validate the IP address as well, but it seems to be returning every single bit of data.. <td>(.*?)<\/td><td>(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)<\/td>

Answer (score 0):

The first `(.*)` matches as much as it possibly can unless you tell it otherwise, so it matches all but the last `<td>`. Then the second `(.*)` matches the contents of the last `<td>`.

The *pattern* matches the whole string. The groups match:

```
over079</td><td>37.123.86.116</td></tr><tr><td>1346968</td><td>rektheace</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>1346967</td><td>rektheace
```

and

```
173.245.67.214
```

respectively.

If you want the groups to match the minimum possible, make them non-greedy with `(.*?)`. The pattern will then match

```
<td>over079</td><td>37.123.86.116</td>
```

And the groups will match the contents of the first two `<td>`s

Comment: Thanks for your post, when I do do this - and make it display the first group it displays most of that line for some reason.